# MVC4 ListBox Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, listbox

I am trying to populate a list box

```
@Html.ListBox("Employees", new MultiSelectList((IEnumerable<CubicHRM.Data.Entities.Employee>)(ViewData["Employees"]) as SelectList, "UserID", "UserName"), new { id = "sourceItems", Multiple = "multiple" })
```

which gives following exception

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
```

Can ayone tell what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thing did it

```
@Html.ListBox("Employees", (MultiSelectList)ViewData["Employees"],  new { id = "sourceItems", Multiple = "multiple" })
```